# How to set icon size displayed at the orange Firefox button?

Tags: css, image, firefox, stylish

```
  #main-window #appmenu-button{
    background:transparent !important;  
    background-color:transparent !important;
    box-shadow: rgb(252,252,252) -0.5px -0.5px 0.5px !important;
            border: 1px solid rgba(245,245,245,0.899) !important;
            border-radius: 0.25em !important;
    outline: 1px solid rgba(222,225,225,0.799) !important;
            -moz-outline-radius: 0.3em !important;
            outline-offset: -1px !important;
    list-style-image:url("chrome://branding/content/icon16.png") !important;
    min-width:78px !important;
    padding-right:56px !important;
    margin-right:-56px !important;
    padding-left:0px !important;
    margin-left:0px !important;
 }
```

This is a part of a userstyle's code which use to display an icon(a little Firefox) and an add-on called *FlipClock* at **the orange Firefox button**.

I want to replace the `chrome://branding/content/icon16.png` (the little Firefox) with another image. But, the image I applied to is too large.

- The full stylish code: [tny.cz/44499fac](http://tny.cz/44499fac)
- The original orange Firefox button:
  [image: orig btn]
- After the userstyle is applied:
  [image: styled btn]
- [The image I want to use (Click for proper image):

  [image: desired image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w059u.png)
- This is what my attempts look like:
  [image: my results]

How do I set the size of it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to scale a `list-style-image` with CSS.
Reference:

- [CSS spec for `list-style-image`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-image)
- ["CSS list-style-image size"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7775594/331508)

So, your only recourse is to resize the image -- which you can do with one of many image editors.  For information on how to do that and retain the transparency, search and/or ask on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) and/or [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

However, I took the liberty of shrinking that image for you. Here it is, sized 32x32 and 16x16, with the transparency preserved.
Note that reducing large images down, does not always make a good icon. ;)

> [16x16: [image: 16px logo]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcuZW.png)
>
> [32x32: [image: 32px logo]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alLgp.png)

(Shown with gray background to demonstrate that transparency is preserved.)

Answer (score 0):

Use photoshop or some other software to re-size your image, and make a alpha layered 16x16 PNG image

Comment: I had tried this method.But after I resized it,it's background changed to no transparent.

Comment: attach both images to your images to your question. The original ff logo and the logo u created

Comment: sorry,I have not enough reputation to post images :-(

Comment: you may either upload image when asking question (check toolbar) or upload image to ingur.com and post the link