# How to implement icon fonts like github.com

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons, sass

How do you implement an icon font?

Github uses them extensively on their webpage, yet trying to reproduce their implementation results in failure.

https://github.com/styleguide/css/7.0

See the attempted implementation here:

http://jsfiddle.net/spuder/jsmzm/7/

```
<div id="github">

    <span class="mega-icon mega-icon-blacktocat"></span>

</div>


.mega-icon-blacktocat {
    content:"\f209";
}
```

I've read many pages on icon fonts, and gone through several tutorials with no success

[How to use icon fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129995/how-to-use-icon-fonts)

http://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-ever-thought-about-using-font-face-for-icons/

[Placing Unicode character in CSS content value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393462/placing-unicode-character-in-css-content-value)

Beginner.

*Update*
2013-4-11
The solution provided works great in WebKit, it does not work in firefox 20.0
http://jsfiddle.net/jsmzm/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**here is your fiddle updated**](http://jsfiddle.net/jsmzm/10/)
basically you were missing the data-icon attribute in your span tag

```
  <div id="github"> 
<span data-icon="" class="mega-icon mega-icon-blacktocat"></span>
```

and the reference in your css

```
[data-icon]:before {
  font-family:'Octicons Regular';
  content: attr(data-icon);
  speak: none;
```

Comment: Excellent! I noticed you use the actual UTF character  . Is there a way to use the ascii value instead? I'm trying data-icon="\f209" with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good  article on [How to Use Icon Fonts in Your Website](http://designmodo.com/use-icon-fonts/)

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers don't support the content property to replace an element's contents.  Its really only meant to be used on pseudo elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/jsmzm/11/

```
.mega-icon-blacktocat:before {
    content:"\f209";
}
```