# My gif is too big for my unordered list? any suggestion?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, gif

I am using the "list-style-image" property to make my unordered list list the items using a gif of a basketball. But the gif is too big so it causes the list to have too much space in between each li tag. How do I resize the gif? or anything else that works.

this is the code:

```
ul { list-style-image: url(ball.gif);}
```

please explain your logic. Thank you.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, please review [ask] before asking questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS list-style-image size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775594/css-list-style-image-size)

Comment: Why not just edit the image in an image editor to be smaller?

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to resize the list style images in html.
2 options: resize in external editor, or simply include inline with your content.