# How to increase the size of image used in li tag for list-style-image property

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a list in HTML where I'm displaying an .svg image instead of bullets using list-style-image property

```
        <ul>
           <li> 1</li> 
           <li> 2</li> 
           <li> 3</li> 
           <li> 4</li> 
           <li> 5</li> 
           <li> 6</li> 

                        </ul>

  CSS:  
     li{
        list-style-image: url(../../1/2/new.svg) ;
    }
```

The images are very small and I'm not able to increase the size(height and width) of the image. Is there anyway I can increase the size of the .svg image?

Comment: Check all possible solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775594/css-list-style-image-size