# Change size of Bullet Images in CSS

Tags: css, image, css-selectors, size, html-lists

[image: Image size is too big to be a bullet]

that's the code

```
list-style-image:  url("https://www.boylesoftware.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/checkmark.png") ;
```

I was expecting it be of small size like that of a actual bullet but it turned out too big

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS list-style-image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775594/css-list-style-image-size)

Comment: Have you investigated the CSS ::marker pseudo element?

Comment: Please post more code of what you have tried. Read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can fix that problem applying the below style:

```css
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  list-style: none;
  background-image: url("https://www.boylesoftware.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/checkmark.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  background-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h1>The list-style-image Property</h1>

<p>The list-style-image property replaces the list-item marker with an image:</p>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
.check{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}
</style>
<p>Unordered List <img class="check" src="https://www.boylesoftware.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/checkmark.png" alt="Alternate Text" /><a href="#">Step 1</a></p>
```

Comment: This removes the semantics of a list.